# Problema com users ao publicar aplicação

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server, lado-do-servidor

Estou a utilizar SQL Server 2012, e ao publicar a minha aplicação, tanto no servidor do cliente como no meu pc tudo funciona bem. As `connection strings` para a BD estão correctas, tudo parece bem. Agora onde está o problema? Ao tentar fazer autenticação de um utilizador obtenho o erro:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.
>   )

No meu ficheiro *AuthConfig.cs* tenho:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("Server=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Server"] + ";Database=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Database"] + ";Integrated Security=False;User ID=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserID"] + ";Password=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"] + ";MultipleActiveResultSets=true;",
                        "System.Data.SqlClient", "Users", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

Onde vou buscar os dados (*Server*, *Database*, *UserID* e *Password*) ao meu Web.config

*Web.config*:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcTesteLayout-20131023143453;Integrated Security=False;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcTesteLayout-20131023143453.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="Server" value="CPSI0024\SQLEXPRESS" />
    <add key="Database" value="OleoTorres" />
    <add key="UserID" value="OleoTorres" />
    <add key="Password" value="oleotorres" />
    <add key="ServerArtSoft" value="OLEOTORRES2014" />
    <add key="UserServerArtSoft" value="Admin" />
    <add key="PassServerArtSoft" value="passServ" />
    <add key="pathFiles" value="D:/uploadsOleotorres"></add>
    <add key="pathFilesGerarPDF" value="D:/gerarPDFOleotorres"></add>
  </appSettings>
```

Já procurei várias formas de resolver, mas não consegui arranjar uma solução onde me resolvesse o problema...

Comment: Este erro quer dizer que a instância SQL Server não foi encontrada. Você pode colocar o seu arquivo `Web.config` na pergunta?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, editado

Comment: @CesarMiguel, tente mudar sua connection string apontando para o IP ou para o DNS do servidor, mesmo que seja a própria máquina. Verifique no seu SQL Managment Studio qual é o server name e utilize parecido.

Comment: Pois, mas o meu server name no SQL Managment Studio é "CPSI0024\SQLEXPRESS", que é o que estou a utilizar

Comment: @CesarMiguel Experimente montar a `connectionString` fora da chamada do método `InitializeDatabaseConnection` e em debug verifique como a `connectionString` foi montada.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, verifiquei em debug e o nome da connectionString está correcto. Eu tenho a aplicação a trabalhar correctamente, apenas quando faço publicação da mesma, é que deixa de funcionar a parte dos utilizadores. Não será talvez nenhuma opção no SQL Server? Ou este erro está mesmo a apontar para má configuração do webconfig?

Comment: @CesarMiguel Onde sua aplicação é publicada?

Comment: Tanto na minha máquina (testes), como no servidor do cliente deixa de funcionar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem, após umas boas horas de volta deste problema achei a solução.
Comentei a minha `connectionString` no *web.config*:

```
  <connectionStrings>
<!--<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcTesteLayout-20131023143453;Integrated Security=False;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcTesteLayout-20131023143453.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
```

E eliminei o ficheiro *InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs* que ao criar o projecto no Visual studio.

Pelo que me parece, ele estava a fazer login numa base de dados chamada *localDb* em vez de ser na minha *CPSI0024\SQLEXPRESS*. Até agora pensava que ao usar o *localDb* estava a fazer referência à *CPSI0024\SQLEXPRESS* e não a uma base de dados local à parte...

Ainda assim, obrigado pelas vossas respostas :)

Comment: Alternativamente, você pode configurar sua `connectionString` assim: `<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=CPSI0024\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=False;User ID=seuusuario;Password=senha" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Answer (score 1):

Qual é a versao de Sql Server? Sera 'LocalDb'? E qual é o formato do valor do 'Server' no web.config? (nao escreves o proprio nome aqui, use um nome ficticio). Esta local ou remoto?

Se tens 'Sql Server Management Studio' (SSMS) podes abrir, fazer um 'right click' no nodoa mais acima que representa o BD, escolha 'Properties/Connections', e vé um opcao "Allow remote connections to this server" - essa precisa estar marcado.

Uma suggestao ao lado. Se escreves o connectionString em completo no web.config dentro de seccao "connectionStrings" entao fique mais nitido do buscar simplesmente com `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[chave].ConnectionString`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não encontro a opção "Allow remote connections to this server". Está nas propriedades da minha BD (OleoTorres)?

Comment: Adicionei um screenshot. Nao tenho certeza se o SQL Server Express permite connecão fora da propria maquina. Mas...vendo o teu web.config, o erro parece esta a tentar usar o connection string do 'DefaultConnnection'...por causa da frase: "_Local Database Runtime Error_" e "_Cannot create automatic instance_"...estao a falar do LocalDB...por isso, o problema pode ser mais no comportamento do WebSecurity procurando primeiro um LocalDb ou talves um connection string "DefaultConnection"...nao conheco esta biblioteca.

Comment: Já tenho marcado. Vou ver o que posso fazer na connection string

Comment: @CesarMiguel Parace, segundo a documentacão [InitializeDatabaseConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.initializedatabaseconnection(v=vs.111).aspx) que o primeiro parameter é o _nome_ do connectionString chave, nao o connectionString em si mesma....faz sentido então, que o metodo não encontra um connectionString com o nome que deste (que é um string enteiro) e então, tenta criar um novo BD no LocalDb...

Comment: mas assim não deveria trabalhar nada na aplicação (certo?). E a única coisa que não me está a trabalhar são dados que tenham a haver com utilizadores como login, guardar dados de utilizador logado etc

Comment: Não necesariamente. WebSecurity somente estabileça connecão com os tableos do seguranca e dos utilizadores e papeis. Normalmente são pre-configurados pelo servicos ASP.Net Identity independemente da logica do resto da applicacão. Ate pode exigir um segundo connectionString somente para isso. E, se não encontrar os tabelos, tente criar los num BD propria, as vezes no LocalDb, o que parece esta a acontecer aqui.

Answer (score 1):

Se o banco de dados está numa máquina em separado (como sugere a máquina `CPSI0024`) usando uma instância SQL Server Express, é preciso fazer uma configuração adicional para permitir conexões remotas:

1. <kbd>Iniciar</kbd> > <kbd>Todos os Programas</kbd> > <kbd>Microsoft SQL Server (versão)</kbd> > <kbd>SQL Server Configuration Manager</kbd> (como administrador);
2. Expanda <kbd>SQL Server Network Configuration</kbd>;
3. Clique em <kbd>Protocols</kbd>;
4. Habilite o **TCP/IP**. Opcionalmente, habilite também o **Named Pipes**.

Verifique também se o Firewall está habilitado para permitir Inbound e Outbound Connections para a instância do SQL Server.

Comment: Também não é esse o problema. Pelo menos não resolveu

Comment: Já encontrei a solução. Vou publicar